# Is there a way to schedule assignments in google classroom API

Tags: api, google-classroom

Is there a way one can schedule assignments using classroom API?

Comment: It looks like it is not possible to schedule a publishing date for an assignment with the google classroom API as of yet. You _could_ write something that would use the API to change the assignment status to published based on a schedule, but the scheduling part would have to be custom.

Comment: It is now possible! Use the `scheduledTime` property and make sure to set the `state` property to `DRAFT`
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can't set the schedule of when the assignment should be published through the API. There are a couple of open issues on apps-api-issues [4730](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4730&q=Scheduling&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner) and [5262](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5262&q=Scheduling&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner) stating this problem. You can star that issue and will be notified as soon as any changes occur. One work around might be is to set the state attribute to DRAFT until needing to change the state to PUBLISHED.

```
POST https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWork

{
  "courseId": string,
  "id": string,
  "title": string,
  "description": string,
  "materials": [
    {
      object(Material)
    }
  ],
  "state": enum(CourseWorkState),
  "alternateLink": string,
  "creationTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
  "dueDate": {
    object(Date)
  },
  "dueTime": {
    object(TimeOfDay)
  },
  "maxPoints": number,
  "workType": enum(CourseWorkType),
  "associatedWithDeveloper": boolean,
  "submissionModificationMode": enum(SubmissionModificationMode),

  // Union field details can be only one of the following:
  "assignment": {
    object(Assignment)
  },
  "multipleChoiceQuestion": {
    object(MultipleChoiceQuestion)
  },
  // End of list of possible types for union field details.
}
Fields
```

Comment: I think they are looking for a way to schedule when an assignment is published, not necessarily the due date, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hey @Tiny Giant, I just updated my answer. As of now I don't think it is possible to set the schedule of when the assignment should be published through Google Calssroom API

Answer (score 1):

Update as of 21 June 2017, the API has been updated to allow the setting of a scheduled time (https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork) using the `scheduledTime` field of the CourseWork.

This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760917) has now been marked as Fixed.

Comment: This is correct, and works, although you **also** need to ensure that CourseWork `state` is set as `DRAFT` (it is `PUBLISHED` by default) or the request will be rejected. The state appears to auto update for the CourseWork when the scheduledTime has elapsed without further action required from the user